# How can I invest in mineral rights?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, stock-markets, land

The USA is one of the few countries in the world with privately-owned [mineral rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_rights). Are there methods I can use to gain investment exposure to mineral rights?

I know that I could buy land that have mineral rights, but I'm looking for something something that requires a smaller minimum investment. Are there exchange-traded instruments I can use to gain exposure to mineral rights?

Comment: Have you considered investing in mining companies and/ or the underlying commodities?  Presumably, the value of mineral rights for, say, gold is tightly coupled with the profitability of gold miners and the underlying price of gold.

Comment: @JustinCave Does your suggestion work when mining companies hedge against commodity price fluctuations? (refer to: [When commodity prices rise, do commodity production companies produce lower returns than the commodities?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/130654))

Comment: @Flux - I think you linked back to the current question.  Mining companies can hedge the price of the commodity (hence the suggestion to invest in the underlying commodity as well).  But ultimately, the only real buyer for mineral rights is companies that want to extract those minerals (barring the very small percentage of mineral rights that get bought up by environmental groups to prevent resource extraction).  So those mineral rights are going to end up as assets on the books of mining companies without an easy way to hedge price fluctuations do to things other than commodity prices.

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry, here is the correct link: [When commodity prices rise, do commodity production companies produce lower returns than the commodities?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/130107)